# Converting scancodes to ASCII

Tags: c++, text-editor, allegro5

I'm implementing my own text editor in c++. It's going... ok. ;P

I need a way to turn a keycode (specifically Allegro, they call it scancodes) into an ASCII-char. I can do A-Z easy, and converting those to a-z is easy as well. What I do currently is use a function in Allegro that returns a name from a scancode (al_keycode_to_name), meaning if the key pressed is A-Z it returns "A" to "Z". That's easy peasy, but I can't simply read special characters like ",", ";" etc. That's where I'm having a hard time.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Maybe a library that does this? The real trick is taking different layouts into consideration.

Here's what I have so far, in case anyone's interested. The class InputState is basically a copy of the Allegro inputstate, with added functionality (keyDown, keyUp, keyPress for example):

```
    void AllegroInput::TextInput(const InputState &inputState, int &currentCharacter, int &currentRow, std::string &textString)
    {
        static int keyTimer = 0;
        static const int KEY_TIMER_LIMIT = 15;
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            if (inputState.key[i].keyDown)
            {
                keyTimer++;
            }
            if (inputState.key[i].keyPress)
            {
                keyTimer = 0;
            }

            if ((inputState.key[i].keyPress) || ((inputState.key[i].keyDown) && (keyTimer >= KEY_TIMER_LIMIT)))
            {
                std::string ASCII = al_keycode_to_name(i);

                if ((ASCII.c_str()[0] >= 32) && (ASCII.c_str()[0] <= 126) && (ASCII.length() == 1))
                {
                    textString = textString.substr(0, currentCharacter) + ASCII + textString.substr(currentCharacter, textString.length());
                    currentCharacter++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    switch(i)
                    {
                        case ALLEGRO_KEY_DELETE:
                            if (currentCharacter >= 0) 
                            {
                                textString.erase(currentCharacter, 1);
                            }
                            break;

                        case ALLEGRO_KEY_BACKSPACE:
                            if (currentCharacter > 0) 
                            {
                                currentCharacter--;
                                textString.erase(currentCharacter, 1);
                            }
                            break;

                        case ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT:
                            if (currentCharacter < textString.length())
                            {
                                currentCharacter++;
                            }
                            break;

                        case ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT:
                            if (currentCharacter > 0)
                            {
                                currentCharacter--;
                            }
                            break;
                        case ALLEGRO_KEY_SPACE:
                            if (currentCharacter > 0)
                            {

                                textString = textString.substr(0, currentCharacter) + " " + textString.substr(currentCharacter, textString.length());
                                currentCharacter++;
                            }
                            break;


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't realise I could, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR` event with the `event.keyboard.unichar` value to read text input. `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN` and `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP` correspond to physical keys being pressed. There is not a 1:1 correspondence between them and printable characters.

Say a dead key is being used to convert the two keys `e'` to `é`. You'd get two key down events for `e` and `'` (and neither are useful for capturing the proper input), but one key char event with `é`. Or inversely, maybe somebody mapped `F4` to a macro that unleashes an entire paragraph of text. In that case, you'd have multiple chars for a single key down.

Or a simple test: if you hold down a key for five seconds, you will get one `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN` but multiple `ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_CHAR` as the OS' keyboard driver sends repeat events.

You can use `ALLEGRO_USTR` to easily store these unicode strings.

```
ALLEGRO_USTR *input = al_ustr_new("");

// in the event loop
al_ustr_append_chr(input, event.keyboard.unichar);
```

There's also ways to delete characters if backspace is pressed, etc. You can use the ustr data types with the font add-on directly via `al_draw_ustr(font, color, x, y, flags, input)`, or you can use `al_cstr(input)` to get a read-only pointer to a UTF-8 string.